# PowerShell on Target Machines Fails in TFS 2018 Release Pipeline

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm new to TFS2018 and i am trying to configure CI/CD Pipeline. My Build succeeded and in my release pipeline, i need to run powershell script on my deployment server and so i used RUN PowerShell on Target  Machine task. I suppose, provided all required info correctly and ran the release but got the error at this task as follows

`Connecting to remote server xxx.xxx.xx.xx failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. Default authentication may be used with an IP address under the following conditions: the transport is HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit credentials are provided. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. For more information on how to set TrustedHosts run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.`

Please find my task config captured below

[image]

[image]

I tried adding my TFS2018 server as trustedHost on target server but still issue exists. Please suggest and help.

Comment: Did you open WinRM port in the target machine?

Comment: @Shayki Abramczyk - I'm not very sure on this. I tried the command `Configure-SMRemoting.exe -enable` in powershell and it shows `Server Manager Remoting is already enabled` . Does it make sense?

Comment: According to the promote message ` the transport is HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit credentials are provided.` Not sure Http is support in your case.  Have you tried to use HTTPS to communicate with the target machine(s). More details about WinRM configuration for both HTTP and HTTPs, please refer this link：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-winrm?view=azure-devops#winrm-configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the TFS server machine to TrustedHost in Target machine through powershell.
   `Set-Item WSMan:localhost\client\trustedhosts -value ServerDC`
2. Ensure credentials provided in this task is of admin role and at same time they have access w.r.to TFS in this case. If provided credentials does not have TFS admin previlage, the task cannot invoke agent to trigger `VisualStudioRemoteDeployer`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is called the double hop problem with PowerShell, usually it means you are trying to log on to a remote machine with different credentials then the credentials your user is running under.  So in your case, is $(adminUserName) the same as the agent? If not then you could try and change that user to be the same as the agent.  If not, then you need to do a little more then add the machine to trustedHost.  Watch this video on SPN it might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFgdPcLOs-g and here is a detailed explanation on the double hop issue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7