# TFS task Run Power shell on remote machine Error: System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Failed to install 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer'

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-pipelines, powershell-2.0

In my TFS 2018 CD, i have a task `Run PowerShell on remote Machine' and it failed with error as follows

`System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Failed to install 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer`

Find the task config as below

[image]

Find the complete error log as follows

`2020-05-05T06:49:22.4862201Z Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain the user information."
2020-05-05T06:49:22.4862692Z  CategoryInfo :NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
2020-05-05T06:49:22.4862987Z  FullyQualifiedErrorId :Exception
2020-05-05T06:49:22.4863348Z  ---> System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain the user information."
2020-05-05T06:49:22.4863751Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2020-05-05T06:49:22.4864154Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.Invoke(String errorContextMessage, Boolean writeResultToLog, Boolean isCancellable)
2020-05-05T06:49:22.4864655Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.RemoteDeploymentHelper.InstallServiceInternal(String serviceSourcePath, String serviceName, String destinationFileName)
2020-05-05T06:49:22.4865266Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.RemoteDeploymentHelper.InstallService(String serviceSourcePath, String serviceName, String destinationFileName)
2020-05-05T06:49:22.4865783Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.DeploymentClient.<RunAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
2020-05-05T06:49:22.4866260Z ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain the user information."<---
2020-05-05T06:49:22.4866523Z 
2020-05-05T06:49:22.4866665Z 
2020-05-05T06:49:22.5010643Z Deployment status for machine 'XXXXX:5985' : 'Failed'
2020-05-05T06:49:22.5565354Z ##[error], MethodInvocationException\r\n FullyQualifiedErrorId :Exception\r\n"}};]
2020-05-05T06:49:22.5588511Z 
2020-05-05T06:49:22.5588871Z 
2020-05-05T06:49:22.5951437Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Failed to install 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployerc87a55d0-555b-426c-b80f-1cf90ad0bf1c' from service executable path VisualStudioRemoteDeployer.exe . Consult the logs below:
2020-05-05T06:49:22.5952932Z Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain the user information."
2020-05-05T06:49:22.5953641Z  CategoryInfo :NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
2020-05-05T06:49:22.5954109Z  FullyQualifiedErrorId :Exception
2020-05-05T06:49:22.5954536Z  ---> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Failed to install 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployerc87a55d0-555b-426c-b80f-1cf90ad0bf1c' from service executable path VisualStudioRemoteDeployer.exe . Consult the logs below:
2020-05-05T06:49:22.5955018Z Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain the user information."
2020-05-05T06:49:22.5955350Z  CategoryInfo :NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
2020-05-05T06:49:22.5955636Z  FullyQualifiedErrorId :Exception
2020-05-05T06:49:22.5955873Z 
2020-05-05T06:49:22.5956133Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2020-05-05T06:49:22.5956455Z    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
2020-05-05T06:49:22.5959512Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
2020-05-05T06:49:22.5959955Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
2020-05-05T06:49:22.5960388Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
2020-05-05T06:49:22.5960842Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
2020-05-05T06:49:22.5961295Z    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Handlers.LegacyVSTSPowerShellHost.VSTSPowerShellHost.Main(String[] args)
2020-05-05T06:49:22.6472008Z ##[error]LegacyVSTSPowerShellHost.exe completed with return code: -1.`

Comment: Is the provided user credentials admin credentials ?

Comment: Yes, these are of admin role

Comment: Does the account that runs the agent have admin rights on the target machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks pretty related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61588090/powershell-on-target-machines-fails-in-tfs-2018-release-pipeline/61610336#61610336) question. Root cause should be related to user access. 
Ensure that user credentials provided in config has admin privileges over target machine and TFS. This would unblock the `VisualStudioRemoteDeployer` to run and eradicate `SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain the user information` issue.